# Angularjs lazy load chartjs when in another tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js

I have the  following canvas in a tab that is not possible to show after page fully loads:

```
<canvas class="chart chart-radar m-t-xs" data="level" labels="label"></canvas>
```

The data for this chart are collected using a `$http` request (so lazy loaded).

Now when the page loads up if I instantly click on the tab then the chart shows and everyone is happy :)

However if I (as a normal user would) stay on the tab when the data is loaded into the chart and then change tab the chart is not visible (like it is not rendering).

This is not the first time I've had this problem and was hoping that someone out there has experianced the same as me and know a work around?

Comment: can you provide the working code in plunkr ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the chart when you OPEN the tab (you can get the data required, just don't use it to create the chart before your tab is open) and not before - so basically, lazy render your chart :-)

fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/3x7uu5eh/

This is the section that shows our tab content AND draws the chart

```
// this is our show tab
$("#tabButton").bind("click", function () {
    $("#tabPane").show();

    // move this section out of this function to see the issue
    var ctx = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
    var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data);
})
```

If you move the marked section out of the show tab, the chart won't render - illustrating the problem.